# Binary XML file line #7: Duplicate id 0xffffffff, tag dialog, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to display a `DialogFragment` which contains a `fragment`.

**Consider the following:**

I have a DialogFragment `EntryFragment` and inside it there is a `textview`. On click of a `textview`, I am trying to open another DialogFragment `PopUpFragment`, but getting an error.

**Error Log:**

```
12-03 14:08:49.527: E/AndroidRuntime(3610): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #7: Duplicate id 0xffffffff, tag dialog, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.savior.main.ContainerFragment
12-03 14:08:49.527: E/AndroidRuntime(3610): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:285)
12-03 14:08:49.527: E/AndroidRuntime(3610): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
```

Please note that the `PopUpFragment` contains a fragment `ContainerFragment`.

**popupfragment.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:padding = "10dp"
             android:tag="dialog"
             class="com.savior.main.ContainerFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

On textview click, the **PopUpFragment.java** is called with this codebase,

```
PopUpFragment cf = new PopUpFragment().newInstace();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("FIELDS", fields);
bundle.putString("LINK-UUID", uuid);
cf.setArguments(bundle);
cf.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

This is my actual **PopUpFragment.java** relevant code,

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    dbAdapter = SaviorDbAdapter.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setView(getContentView());
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    fields = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("FIELDS");
        uuid = bundle.getString("uuid");
        dialog = builder.create();      
    return dialog;
}


private View getContentView() {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popupfragment, null);

           return view;
}
```

Comment: Are you using the support library?  I am actually having a very similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem I did thoose two changes:

1. declare rootView as static inside the fragment class

   ```
   protected static View rootView = null;
   ```
2. in onCreateView method check if rootView is null

   ```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
           if( rootView == null )
               rootView = super.onCreateView( inflater, container, savedInstanceState );

           if( rootView != null )
               setUpMap();
   }
   ```

I hope this solution can help you.